# How to get the MTL file associated with a OBJ created by Forge DerivativeApi?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I've created a OBJ derivative from a F3D file with Forge DerivativeApi.

I also was able to download the OBJ derivative via getDerivativeManifest().

BUT:
Where is, and how to get, the MTL file associated with and referenced in the OBJ file created by Forge?

getManifest() gives no information about a MTL file, just about the OBJ itself.

Regards,
Michael

Comment: MTL is not supported yet by Model Derivatives API, you can only export a non-textured obj :(

Comment: So why does Autodesk reference an MTF file inside the OBJ if they don't support/create it ...

I feel that Forge is very inconsistent in many cases...

Comment: @Philippe is there any "roadmap" related to implementing the MTL file generation?